#  Can't debug on iOS 4.x devices

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

Whenever I try to debug on devices with iOS 4.x (iPhone 4 and 3GS) I get the following error:

```
error: failed to launch '/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-fytptbaixvmoweacfsniqxtvjkst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXX.app/XXX' 
  -- Bad CPU type in executable
```

On devices with iOS 5.x it works.

I am using xCode 4.3.3 and my configurations are:

- Architectures: Standard (armv7) (also tried armv6,armv7 to no avail)
- Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 5.1)
- Valid Architectures: armv6, armv7
- Deployment Target: iOS 4.0

What do you think?

Comment: Your base SDK is iOS 5.1. What's your targeted OS version?

Comment: Did you remove armv7 from the Required Device Capabilities in your .plist?

Comment: @StevenLuu the deployment target is iOS 4

Comment: What is the value for "Build active architecture"?

Answer (score 0):

In your Xcode preferences, go to downloads tab and install "iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support".

> This package includes information and symbols that Xcode needs for
>   debugging your app on iOS devices running versions of iOS prior to iOS
>   4.2.  If you intend to debug your app on a device running one of these versions of iOS you should install this package.